# Bulk insert, update and check existing values with peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm making a script that scraps data from an online store, these data are organized like this:

```
[{
    'productId': '5f170553385e3156009c234d',
    'productName': 'iPhone 15 Pro Max',
    'productPrice': 1999,
    'productAvailability': True
}]
```

I made a peewee table like this:

```
class OnlineStore(Model):
    productId = TextField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    productName = TextField()
    productPrice = SmallIntegerField()
    productAvailability = BooleanField()
    priceHasChanged = BooleanField(default=False)
```

The script is supposed to export (in xlsx format) certain products' data highlighting availability and if price has changed.

My initial thought was to bulk update/insert and also setting `priceHasChanged`, but couldn't know how to do that.

I think I can do that in different approach where I modify the table to be:

```
class OnlineStore(Model):
    productId = TextField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    productName = TextField()
    productPrice = SmallIntegerField()
    productOldPrice = SmallIntegerField()
    productAvailability = BooleanField()
```

The script has to update existing data first, copying `productPrice` to `productOldPrice` then does bulk update/insert, So in the last stage (export) it compare prices and does highlighting accordingly, but this way doesn't seem effecient. especially when there are lots of export requests.

How to do that the most effecient way?

Comment: You can set a uniqueness constraint on whatever uniquely identifies the item, then use postgres INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE to update the price and set the "has changed" flag.

Comment: @coleifer I'm using `productId` as primary key, so if a product already exists, I can use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` but how can I tell if `productPrice` is different and how to act accordingly?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head, sorry.